# Twitter/Facebook Question Sharing Links

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I may be being blind, but in the new design I can't see the buttons to share a question on Twitter/Facebook/whatever, that were there in the beta design. Are they going to be re-added at some point?

Comment: is there any update on this question? I still can't see the links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Edd they will be implemented soon.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for confirming I'm not being blind!

Comment: Just seen this has been added. Thanks Jin! Do you (or any other mod) want to tag this as status-complete?

Answer (score 0):

That will be really useful - save me copying and pasting